# Liquibase generateChangeLog - How to exclude some data and keep all ddl change logs in single execution?

Tags: liquibase

I'm using the `generateChangeLog` goal of the Liquibase maven plugin to produce a full change log of my target database. However currently I need to exclude some tables for the data part of the export because they contain too much data and I get an `OutOfMemory` exception.

Is it possible to use `diffExcludeObjects` or `diffIncludeObjects` to only exclude/include tables for the data part of the change log, whilst using all of the tables for the ddl parts?

I have tried separating the run into three separate executions which use the following diffTypes

- tables,views,columns,primarykeys
- data
- foreignkeys,uniqueconstraints,indexes

However when doing this I am faced with the following error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.251 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-26T13:49:08+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/981M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.0:generateChangeLog (workflow-ddl-generate) on project CalmsLiquibaseBaselineGeneration: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Could not resolve UnexpectedObjectChangeGenerator dependencies due to dependency cycle. Dependencies:
[ERROR] [] -> Table -> []
[ERROR] [] -> View -> []
[ERROR] [] -> PrimaryKey -> []
[ERROR] [] -> Schema -> []
[ERROR] [ForeignKey] -> Column -> []
[ERROR] [] -> Catalog -> []
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just try increasing the memory given to the Liquibase JVM and keeping it all in one run.

Comment: Although this may work, I don't actually want the data from the certain subset of tables in the outputted change log. The separate executions would achieve what I need, however this doesn't seem possible as you can see from the error log.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a way to have it generate only schema for some tables and schema+data for others. The most expedient suggestion is to post-process the changelog. The other option is to either submit a feature request to Liquibase (which may take a VERY long time to get addressed since there are very few developers working to add features to Liquibase) or else implement it yourself and submit a pull request.